# Every time I click checkbox it takes checked state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Let me be specific when I click checkbox it takes checked state (I have 2 check box) the first one is correct and second one is incorrect, if I click first one and after click second one but after I click first one again and I click "next" It saved 2 correct state but this is a big problem because at the end I need count how many answers are correct and this changes the % of correct answers. What Can I do to save only one time the checkbox?

```js
state = 0;
var pMin = 1;
var pMax = <? php echo $count ?> ;
var respuestas = [];
var correcto = 0;
var incorrecto = 0;
porcentaje = 0;

function play(pfile) {
  console.log(pfile);

  var source = '<audio id="audio_player"><source id="audio_player_ogv" src="audios/' + pfile + '.ogg"  type="audio/ogg"  /><source id="audio_player_ogv" src="audios/' + pfile + '.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>';
  $('#divAudio_Player').html(source);
  var aud = $('#audio_player').get(0);
  aud.play();
}

function ActivecheckAnswers(e) {
  $("#p" + pMin + " .boton").addClass("ver2");
}

function checkAnswers(e) {
  $("#p" + pMin + " .respuesta").addClass("ver");
}
$(".sonido li").click(function() {
  console.log(this.className);
});

function Califica(opc) {
  $(".continuar").addClass("ver");
  respuestas[pMin] = opc;
  if (opc == 1) {
    correcto++;
    $("#p" + pMin + " .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', true);
    $("#p" + pMin + " .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', false);
    $('.opc1').on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.button').show();
      } else {
        $('.button').hide();
      }
    });

  } else if (opc == 2) {
    incorrecto++;
    $("#p" + pMin + " .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', false);
    $("#p" + pMin + " .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', true);
    $('.opc2').on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.button').show();
      } else {
        $('.button').hide();
      }
    });
  }
};

function siguiente() {
  var aud = $('#audio_player').get(0);
  aud.pause();

  $(".plantilla .continuar").removeClass("ver");
  if (pMin < pMax) {
    $("#p" + pMin).removeClass("ver");
    pMin++;
    $("#p" + pMin).addClass("ver");
    state = 0;
  }
  if (pMin == 9) {
    porcentaje = correcto * 100 / (pMax - 1);
    alert("Tienes" + porcentaje + "%correcto");
  }
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div id="general">
    <div hidden>
      <audio id="audio" src=""></audio>
      <div id="divAudio_Player">
        <audio id="audio_player">
          <source id="audio_player_ogv" src="" type="audio/ogg" />
          <source id="audio_player_mp3" src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
      </div>
    </div>


    <ul class="plantilla">
      <?php $count=1 ; while ($count <=9 ) { ?>

      <li id="p<?=$count ?>" <?php if ($count==1){echo "class='ver'";} ?>>
        <img src="img/foto<?=$count ?>.jpg">
        <ul class="sonido">
          <li class="record"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> Record (Grabar)</li>
          <li class="stop"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop (Detener)</li>
          <li class="play"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> Listen (Escuchar)</li>
        </ul>


        <div class="pregunta">I want some roast____.</div>
        <input type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()" value="Check answers" class="boton">

        <div class="respuesta">
          <input type="button" onclick="play('audio<?=$count ?>')" value="I want some roast beef" class="playsound">
          <div class="opciones">
            <p style="margin-left:50px;" class="hh"><b>Evaluate Yourself</b>
            </p>
            <img class="img1" src="img/correcto.png" onClick="Califica(1)">
            <input class="opc1" type="checkbox" value="1" onClick="Califica(1)" />
            <label class="label1" for="label1">Good</label>
            <img class="img2" src="img/incorrecto.png" onClick="Califica(2)">
            <input class="opc2" type="checkbox" value="2" onClick="Califica(2)" />
            <label class="label2" for="label2" style="height:200px; width:50px;">Not Enough</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
<?php
        $count++;

    }
    $count--;
    ?>


      <div class='continuar'>
        <input type="button" onclick="siguiente()" value="Continuar" class="button">
      </div>

    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: it looks like you might be mixing property and attribute, try to stay constant.

Comment: `checked` attribute should has a value of `"checked"`, or it should be removed for not checkeds. `checked` property is a boolean.

Comment: That only changes if that checkbox is checked it shows or hide the button but that doesn´t changes what I want, anyway thanks

Comment: No? You didn't fully understand what I said. Attribute values are _always_ strings, there's no difference if set `true` or `false`, they both are evalueated to a string, and a non-empty string is always evaluated to `true`. The simplest solution is to set `.prop` instead of `.attr` in your case.

Comment: That only doesn´t let me uncheck it but if I continue clicking the checkbox it counts all the clicks that I do and that´s the same, but yes I understand what you say and now I know the difference between .prop and .attr thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the onClick function and add an event listener based on class. Then you can add another class to a clicked item to record when it has been clicked.

Here is a basic example to get you started. There is more that you will need to add in, but it gives you the basic idea of the logic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".opc1").on('change', function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('item-checked')){
            correcto++;
            $(this).addClass('item-checked');
        }
    });

   $(".opc2").on('change', function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('item-checked')){
            incorrecto++;
            $(this).addClass('item-checked');
        }
    });
})
```